# How to build a video wall with multi-streams

Tags: directx, video-streaming, vlc, multimedia

I am attempting to make a mosaic display for our video wall. The mosaic will play video files (wmv) in a matrix view (probably 4x2). I am looking for a programmatic aproach to stream multiple videos using mms.
I have accomplished something similar using vlc mosaic plugin, but it terminates when the first video finishes playing. I am interested in running the tool in a loop.
Here is a vlc mosaic example: https://gist.github.com/1367589

First question, what is the easiest technology that I can implement this in, DirectX SDK, Windows SDK for Media Foundation, OpenGL, libvlc?

Are there any tutorials for multi video playback coding?

Comment: OpenGL is a drawing API, similar to Direct3D, so that one won't help you for video streaming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VLC and gStreamer are good options for this and have support for picture in picture videomixing.